# convert export declare function into a function like ES6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, export, declare

I have an older project that uses a lot of non-ES6 and would like to update things.

There are a lot of declared exports for various functions, such as

```
export declare function myFunction(myArg: CustomArgType): Promise<CustomPromiseType>
```

Is it possible to write this in an ES6 way, declaring it as a constant rather than a function, just as `function abc() {}` is equivalent to `const abc = () => {}`?

Comment: Why do you need that? Do you `.js`+`.d.ts`? It's `export declare const myFunction: (myArg: CustomArgType) => Promise<CustomPromiseType>
`

Comment: `export function myFunction` *is* ES6 way. Function style (`function x(){}` vs `const x = ()=>{}`)  is just a style preference

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/func-style

Comment: Don't be arbitrary. Function statements are fantastic and no es6 construct attempted to replace them. Two benefits include hoisting and the improved readability when expressing complex signatures.